# Given a partially ordered set, remove all smaller items

Tags: clojure

I'm struggling to find a beautiful, idiomatic way to write a function

```
(defn remove-smaller
  [coll partial-order-fn]
  ___
)
```

where `partial-order-fn` takes two arguments and return -1 0 or 1 is they are comparable (resp. smaller, equal, bigger) or `nil` otherwise.

The result of `remove-smaller` should be coll, with all items that are smaller than any other item in coll are removed.

Example: If we defined a partial order such as numbers are compared normally, letters too, but a letter and a number are not comparable:

```
1 < 2    a < t    2 ? a
```

Then we would have:

```
(remove-smaller [1 9 a f 3 4 z])
==> [9 z]
```

Comment: Could you add some sample input and output? "all items that are smaller than any other item in coll are removed." would be a collection with a single item, ie (max coll)

Comment: Sure, I added an example. Actually, `max` would not mean anything if the items are partially ordered (as opposed to totally ordered).

Comment: Just a suggestion: how about calling the function `remove-mins` instead of `remove-smaller`? The current name sounds like you want to remove all entries smaller than a given element.

Comment: I don't understand your input.  How can you compare a letter to a number?

Comment: @DaoWen yeah actually I should have done the contrary and name it `keep-maximums`. Maximums are "mathematically defined" for partially ordered sets. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

Comment: @tieTYT You can't, that's the point with partially ordered sets !

Comment: @Blacksad - Yes, that would be a better name. I misread your post—I thought you were only removing the minimums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice I might just use tom's answer, since no algorithm can guarantee better than O(n^2) worst-case performance and it's easy to read. But if performance matters, choosing an algorithm that is *always* n^2 isn't good if you can avoid it; the below solution avoids re-iterating over any items which are known not to be maxes, and therefore can be as good as O(n) if the set turns out to actually be totally ordered. (of course, this relies on transitivity of the ordering relation, but since you call this a partial order that's implied)

```
(defn remove-smaller [cmp coll]
  (reduce (fn [maxes x]
            (let [[acc keep-x]
                  ,,(reduce (fn [[acc keep-x] [max diff]]
                              (cond (neg? diff) [(conj acc max) false]
                                    (pos? diff) [acc keep-x]
                                    :else [(conj acc max) keep-x]))
                            [[] true], (map #(list % (or (cmp x %) 0))
                                            maxes))]
              (if keep-x
                (conj acc x)
                acc)))
          (), coll))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually trying this performance-aware version with a recursive function but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn partial-compare [x y]
  (when (= (type x) (type y))
    (compare x y)))

(defn remove-smaller [coll partial-order-fn]
  (filter
    (fn [x] (every? #(let [p (partial-order-fn x %)]
                       (or (nil? p) (>= p 0)))
                    coll))
    coll))

(defn -main []
  (remove-smaller [1 9 \a \f 3 4 \z] partial-compare))
```

This outputs `(9 \z)`, which is correct unless you want the return value to be of the same type as `coll`.

Comment: Thanks tom, I accepted @amalloy answer for performance reasons but your version is very clear and readable. I gave it a +1. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
(def data [1 9 \a \f 3 4 \z])

(defn my-fn [x y]
  (when (= (type x) (type y))
    (compare x y)))

(defn remove-smaller [coll partial-order-fn] 
  (mapv #(->> % (sort partial-order-fn) last) (vals (group-by type data))))

(remove-smaller data my-fn)
;=> [9 \z]
```

Potentially the order of the remaining items might differ to the input collection, but there is no order between the equality 'partitions'

Comment: This only works because you've added the assumption that it's easy/cheap to `group-by` into comparability partitions.